# Was Jesus tired due to the stress of the journey, or was he tired from being in routes and among people who weren't his primary focus, the Jews?

Tags: john, matthew, jesus

> Jacob's well was there, so Jesus, since he was tired from the journey, sat right down beside the well. It was about noon.
> Jn. 4:6 NET

> But he answered and said to them, I am not sent but to the sheep which have wandered from the house of Israel. Mt 15:24 Peshito Etheridge

Was Jesus out of the way under pressure from the Pharisees?

Comment: The verse says that Jesus was tired from the journey.  So, what is your question?

Comment: The preposition ek has multiple meanings.

Comment: The second use of "journey" would be symbolic of Mission.

Comment: In Jn.4 Jesus is traveling through Samaria. In Mt.12 Jesus is in Tyre & Sidon from whence he went to a mountain in Galilee. The two situations are unrelated, and the time periods quite distinct. Could you please explain what your question is asking, as your comments above do not clarify anything, and 'out of the way' seems totally disjointed from anything.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is necessary for me to be on the way today and tomorrow and on the next day , because it is not possible for a prophet to perish outside **Jerusalem**. Lc 13:33 The way was always towards Jerusalem.

Answer (score 1):

My answer focuses on the final question: "Was Jesus out of the way under pressure from the Pharisees?" By
"out of the way," I take it the OP refers to the fact that Jesus says he is to go only the lost sheep of Israel, not Samaritans or gentiles.

To go through Samaria was the normal route to travel from Judea to the western shore of Galilee, which was where Jesus spent much of his ministry. John's Gospel does say that Pharisees had heard Jesus was baptizing more people than John the Baptist. Thus, there may indeed by an implication that Jesus wanted to avoid confrontation with them, or to escape scrutiny of Herod Antipas, who was the Baptist's mortal enemy. However, the author says directly: "He left Judea and went away again to Galilee. And He had to pass through Samaria." So his route was not "out of the way."

[image]

However, in Mt. 15:24, Jesus traveled to a non-Jewish area (near Tyre and Sidon) not because it was the shortest route, but intentionally. He went there after an incident in which his disciples warned him that certain Pharisees were offended by his response to their objection to his teaching on eating with unwashed hands. We don't know for certain why he then went from the Galilee the northern coastal area. Here are three possibilities.

- 1. He is several times depicted as feeling a need to get away from the crowds, so it could be as simple as that.
- 2. Or, it could be that he was indeed feeling pressure from those Pharisees mentioned in the OP.
- 3. Finally, Jesus may have fled from the Galilee in response to a warning from a group of Pharisees mentioned in Luke 13:31 in the same general location:  “Go away and leave this place, because Herod  wants to kill You.”

Choices 2 and 3 may be related if the Pharisees in Mt. 15 and Luke 13 were the same group, and they told Jesus to get out of town as a threat rather than a friendly warning.

**Regarding the story in John 4, Jesus chose the normal route. It may be that he was concerned about scrutiny from Pharisees, who were less active in Galilee than in Judea. Regarding the story in Mt. 15, the disciples warned him that he had offended certain Pharisees shortly before he traveled the area of Trye and Sidon. But there are several reasons he might have gone there, as indicated above.**

Comment: Mt 15:24 Jesus is saying that the target of the walk is Jerusalem and not Galilee and Samaria.